# Django admin/template does not change the value that changed in mysql?

Tags: django, ubuntu, uwsgi

On the production appeared a strange bug, there is a table **blog_category_translation** with fields **id | language_code | name | master_id** sql query: `mysql> select * from blog_category_translation;
+----+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| id | language_code | name             | master_id |
+----+---------------+------------------+-----------+
|  1 | ru            | New Category RU |         1 |`
in field **name** there is value **New Category RU**  Then through the admin area I change this value to  **New Category RU1**, again sql query: 
`mysql> select * from blog_category_translation;
+----+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| id | language_code | name             | master_id |
+----+---------------+------------------+-----------+
|  1 | ru            | New Category RU1 |         1 |`
That's fine. But not in admin-panel: [admin panel, don't change value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQjX4.png)

But there is an old value. If reload page **there is new value**, if i yet reload page **there is new value**, if i yet reload page **there is old value**, etc. Django toggle value in view. Sorry for my bad english (((. I used **Emperor mode**:[digitalocean.com Emperor mode](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I feel you reloading through reload button in browser. Ii will re submit data. So click on url and do `enter`

Comment: @itzMEonTV  i tried. But the problem is the same.